# Swiftui DisclosureGroup content and label different background color

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build the below design in `Swiftui` using `DisclosureGroup` but when I apply background to the whole `DisclosureGroup` it becomes `content` background color as well, and when I try to set background color for the `label` then it doesn't cover the arrow area. in addition, when I remove the background color the label color becomes transparent.

The design I try to build:

[image]

The design I got:

[image]

The code:

```
return VStack {
                        List (self.levelsListVM.userLevels, id:\.id ) { level in
                                VStack {
                                    DisclosureGroup(

                                        content: {
                                            HStack{
                                                disclosureSubView(userTopics: level.userLevel.userTopics)
                                                
                                            }
                                        },
                                        label: {
                                            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                                                ImageDisplay(imageURL: level.imageUrl)
                                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                                    .background(Color(red: 0.4627, green: 0.8392, blue: 1.0))
                                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                                    
                                                    
                                                     .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                                                    Text(level.name)
                                                    HStack {
                                                        Text("Level \(level.number) ").font(.footnote)
                                                        Text("0 / 2 / 1").font(.caption)
          
                                                    }
                                                   
                                                    
                                                }.padding(.leading, 10)
                                                
                                                
                                                Spacer()

                                            }

                                        })
                                        .padding()
                                        // 5.
                                       
                                        .background(Color.white)


                                }.cornerRadius(30)

                                .padding(1)

                                Spacer()
                            }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                        }.padding(1)

            }
```

The question is how to set background color only for the label?

Comment: You may have better luck if you include a [mre]. No one can compile the code you've included since it depends on information not included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your color modifier on the label "view":

```
label: {
  HStack(spacing: 5) {
    ImageDisplay(imageURL: level.imageUrl)
      .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
      .background(Color(red: 0.4627, green: 0.8392, blue: 1.0))
      .clipShape(Circle())
    
    
      .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
      Text(level.name)
      HStack {
        Text("Level \(level.number) ").font(.footnote)
        Text("0 / 2 / 1").font(.caption)
      }
    }.padding(.leading, 10)
    Spacer()
  }
}
.background(Color.purple)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had success with a similar problem by removing `List` and just putting your UI in VStacks. As long as it's not too many items this may work for you.